# Mysql search match and order

Tags: mysql, sql

When I set `$file_name_keyword` to Iron Man 3, it returns me also Iron Man 2 results or vice versa, it is not even problem, but how to make it to return first order all Iron Man 3 entries and then Iron Man 2 ?
Please note ORDER BY votes - votes are set to 0, its the same for all entries now.

```
SELECT *,MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword')
FROM `uploaded`
WHERE (MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword')
       OR file_name_keyword REGEXP '.*($file_name_keyword).*')
AND active = '1'
ORDER BY `votes`
```

returns me something like

```
Iron.Man.2. Multi5.PAL.Nintendo.DS .By.Gamolama.torrent
Iron.Man.3.2013.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
Iron Man 2 Multi5 PAL Nintendo DS By Gamolama torrent
Iron Man 3 2013 720p BluRay x264 YIFY mp4
Iron Man 2 2010 1080p BDRip AAC x264-tomcat12 torrent
iron man 2 wallpaper-1920x1080 jpg
```

Thanks in advance, this is what I ended up and dont know how to improve it.

Table structure [MyISAM]

```
id - int(11)
file_name - varchar(255) - server generated
file_size - int(11)
file_ext - varchar(255)
file_name_keyword - varchar(255) - user generated e.g. original file name
upload_datetime - datetime
votes - int(11)
active - int(1)
```

Comment: what kind of SQL is this ? MATCH isn't a standard function - you might get better answers if you include a tag for the correct version of sql e.g. SQL Server or MySQL, Oracle etc ...

Comment: @bhs I think this is MySQL, but the OP should tag his question with the RDBMS he's using.

Comment: Added mysql tag as those seem to be specific features related to mysql

Comment: Sorry, that was mysql, forgot. @Prix yes I've tried, it returns same success.

Comment: @WigglerJtag what is your table structure?

Comment: It is MyISAM and it holds all the information about the file e.g. id, file_name (unique), file_size, file_ext, file_name_keyword is the original name under which user uploads a file, upload_datetime, votes and active.

Comment: update your question with your table structure listing each field types etc.

Comment: Try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thanks, will take a look, though its only for InnoDB and now I see its exactly for MyISAM!

Comment: @Prix so I've done `AGAINST('+Iron+Man+2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` and it still returns me same output as before.. where could be the problem? Was following completely the manual. Removed from the SQL OR REGEXP and still no success.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is important to note that Full Text Searching in mySQL is sensitive to **word length**. Identifier i.e. `ft_min_word_len`, any word length below this length will be ignored by the search indexing and thus won't appear in the results. [Fine Tuning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) will help you address this min-max value issue.

For your query you could try below for ordering

```
SELECT *,MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') as relevancy
FROM `uploaded`
WHERE MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword')
AND active = '1'
ORDER BY relevancy DESC, `votes` DESC
```

**TIPS**
For more details on FullTEXT [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)..

Comment: Thanks, it ordered first results are Iron Man 3 and then Iron Man 2, but if I search for Iron Man 2, then on top is 3, so does not work, hm :/

Comment: Anyway just came in my mind, how it should order, if the file_name_keyword is something like Iron Man 3 2010 1080p BDRip AAC x264-tomcat12 torrent, it contains more 2 than 3 numbers, how could I order my results by the first decimal after the string? So it ignores all numbers behind.

Comment: There is a limitation with FULL TEXT SEARCHING, It doesn't allow search and ranking based on Regular expression. If you want to search on field where values come from users, then you might have to look for other searching methods.. I am not sure though..